# add a layout dynamically to the parent. (NullPointerException)

Tags: android-layout

I want to add a Linear Layout to the RelativeLayout of my Activity, the one that comes with the Activity. But when I add, I get a nullpointerException.

I want to achive this hierarchy:

```
  Layout principal

     Layout contenedor

          edittext    edittext    edittext
```

What am I doing wrong?

Hier is the Code:

```
LinearLayout contenedorPuntajes;
Button cargarPuntajes;
RelativeLayout principal;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    principal = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutPrincipal);//i have given an id to the main RelativeLayout that comes with the activity (default) 


    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cargar_puntajes);

    cargarPuntajes = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cargarPuntajes);

    contenedorPuntajes= new LinearLayout(this);
    contenedorPuntajes.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));


    contenedorPuntajes.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

    ArrayList<EditText> editTexts = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i=0; i<3;i++){
        EditText etxt = new EditText(this);
        etxt.setHint("00");
        etxt.setMaxEms(2);
        editTexts.add(etxt);
        contenedorPuntajes.addView(etxt);
    }

    cargarPuntajes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            principal.addView(contenedorPuntajes);//here i get the exception
        }
    });
```

thankyou

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    principal = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutPrincipal);//i have given an id to the main RelativeLayout that comes with the activity (default) 


    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cargar_puntajes);
```

You should reorder the `setContentView` and the `findViewById` lines. First set the content view, then find a view.